# Android native maps api or webview?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I was wondering what the benefits or drawbacks of using either the Google maps api that is native or using a webview that points to Google maps online? The issue is that sometimes the native maps throws an exception that seems to be a know bug. I am thinking about switching to the webview because this know bug in the native maps library doesn't seem that it will be fixed soon. Any insite on the difference would be appreciated.

Comment: This article goes through the options: [Overview of Mobile Development Options for the Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/mobile_overview_v3.html)

Answer (score 0):

if your goal is just to show a map, then you can go for any of them. but if you intent to add pins on your map to show locations or to show an arrow that's moving on the map or if you want to draw lines on the map then you'll definitely need the native map api.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with maps on a webview is scrolling and zooming.

Depending on what you want you can also cal google maps using it's [intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html)